# Как работают циклы?

Tags: java, циклы

Обучаюсь Java, но самая сложная тема для меня это циклы. При чем все. Сейчас уже начались массивы, а циклы все также не укладываются в голове. Нет понимания откуда берутся формулы и выходные значения.
Вот например:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int list[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
        for (int i = 1; i < list.length; i++)
            list[i] = list[i - 1];

        for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
            System.out.print(list[i] + " ");

    }
}
```

- Почему 1 1 1 1 1 1 получается?
- Как расчет происходит?

Вложенные циклы еще сложнее: нет понимания в каком порядке срабатывают циклы или одновременно.
Вот пример:

```
        int i, j;
        // отобразить верхнюю половину и центральный ряд
        for (i = 1; i <= 5; ++i) {
            for (j = 0; j < i; ++j)
                System.out.print("  " + j);
            System.out.println();
        }

 //отобразить нижнюю половину
        for (i = 5; i > 0; --i) {
            for (j = 0; j < i; ++j)
                System.out.print("  " + j);
            System.out.println();
        }
```

Заранее благодарю за ответы.

Comment: `Как расчет происходит?` Ну какой расчёт - в каждую ячейку копируется левый сосед. Начинаем слева - вот первая ячейка и копируется во все.

Comment: Тут есть только один способ понять. Берёте бумажку, записываете значения всех переменных и идёте последовательно по коду. Вручную отрабатываете цикл - инициализация, проверка выхода из цикла, изменение переменной цикла, всё вручную, записывая текущие значения всех переменных после каждого шага. Так придёт понимание. Дальше будете делать тоже самое уже в голове. А дальше это уже и не нужно будет, так будете понимать. С вложенными циклами тоже самое - начинаете с бумажки. И последовательно идёте по коду, работая интерпретатором кода.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В первом цикле, вы наверное, хотите вычитать единицу из значения содержащегося в массиве. Но по факту вы каждому значению(начиная со второго т.е. 2) присваиваете значение предыдущего.
i - в данном случае это не значение, а его индекс в массиве.

```
int list[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
    for (int i = 1; i < list.length; i++)
        list[i] = list[i - 1];


i = 1 
list[i] = 2
```

Индекс представляет номер элемента в массиве, при этом нумерация начинается с нуля, поэтому индекс первого элемента будет равен 0, индекс шестого элемента - 5.

```
i = 1
list[i] = list[i - 1];
```

Так как i = 1, вычитаем из него 1, получаем 0

Получается что `list[1] = list[0]`
Приравниваем значение из первого индекса ко второму. В первом индексе у нас 1.
При последующем переборе у вас происходит та же процедура, но в предыдущем значении уже 1 и она приравнивается всем индексам массива.

Если вы вынесете за скобки -1, т.е. `list[i] = list[i] - 1` то тогда вы будете вычитать 1 из значения данного индекса.

Сам цикл `for (int i = 1; i < list.length; i++)` представляет довольно простое условие.

Первая часть объявления цикла - `int i = 1` - создает и инициализирует переменную i.

Вторая часть - условие `i < list.length`. То есть пока переменная i меньше длины массива, будет выполняться цикл.
length - общее число элементов во всех измерениях массива.

Третья часть - действия, выполняемые после завершения тела цикла - увеличение переменной i на единицу.

Вложенные циклы работают все по тому же принципу.
Выполняется условие родительского цикла, потом происходит выполнение вложенного цикла от начала условия до его конца. После чего происходит проверка условия родительского цикла и так по кругу, пока условие родительского цикла не перестанет выполняться.

И да, совет про пошаговый разбор работы цикла на бумаге с карандашом это очень хороший совет, который применим не только к циклам, не оставьте его без внимания.

Comment: Да нет, не чат. Это у меня в VBA потянуло, если Option Base 1 поставить и нижняя граница массивов начинается с 1. Спасибо за замечание, исправлю.

Comment: Спасибо за разъяснение, теперь поняла. На бумаге действительно легче приходит понимание.